# Show that there exists a constant $C > 0$ such that $\lVert u\rVert_{H^1_0 (U)} ≤ C$ for all weak solutions $u$.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $n > 2$ and let $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function satisfying
$$\lvert f(t)\rvert ≤ c \lvert t\rvert^{q−1}\quad \forall t \in \mathbb R,$$
for some constants $c > 0$ and $1 \leq q < 2$. We say that $u \in H^1_0(U)$ is a weak solution of
$$ −\Delta u = f(u) \text{ in } U,$$
$$u = 0 \text{ on } \partial U,$$
if $$\int_U \nabla u\cdot\nabla v \, dx = \int_U f(u) v\, dx \quad \forall v \in H^1_0(U).$$
Show that there exists a constant $C > 0$ such that $\lVert u\rVert_{H^1_0(U)} \leq C$
for all weak solutions u.

Can anyone give me an idea about how to solve this? Very much appreciated for any thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: There is $$\|u\|_{H^1}^2 \approx (-\Delta u, u) \leq \frac{1}{2\varepsilon}\|\Delta u\|_{H^{-1}}^2 + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\|u\|_{H^1} \implies \|u\|_{H^1}^2 \leq C\|-\Delta u\|_{H^{-1}}^2 = C\|f(u)\|_{H^{-1}}^2$$, but it doesn't seem to help?

Comment: It does seem to help. Thanks. but I don't see anything about how to derive the required condition that the norm of H^10(U) is bounded by a constant C

Comment: And also I don’t think we need dual space of H^1_0 here in this problem. It is just by using the weak formulation but couldn’t figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the definition of $u\in H^1_0(U)$ being a weak solution to $-\Delta u =f(u)$, we can use $u$ as a test function (since $u\in H^1_0(U)$) to obtain that $$ \| \nabla u \|^2_{L^2(U)}  = \int_U \vert \nabla u \vert^2 \, dx = \int_Uf(u) u \, dx . $$ Using the assumption on $f$, we have that $$ \| \nabla u \|^2_{L^2(U)}  \leqslant C \int_U\vert u\vert^q \, dx  \tag{$1$} .$$ Next, assuming that $\Omega$ is bounded, by Hölder's inequality with $p=2/q>1$, it follows that $$ \int_U\vert u\vert^q \, dx \leqslant \vert U\vert^{1-\frac q2} \bigg ( \int_U\vert u\vert^2 \, dx \bigg)^{q/2} \tag{$2$}. $$

Finally, using again that $\Omega$ is bounded, the [Poincaré inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality) implies that $$\|u\|_{H^1(U)}^2 \leqslant C \| \nabla u \|^2_{L^2(U)} . \tag{$3$}$$ with $C=C(U)$.

Combining ($1$), ($2$), and ($3$) gives $$ \| u\|_{H^1(U)}^2 \leqslant C(\Omega,q) \bigg ( \int_U\vert u\vert^2 \, dx \bigg)^{q/2} \leqslant C(\Omega,q)\|u\|_{H^1(U)}^q.   $$ To obtain the final result, divide both sides by $\|u\|_{H^1(U)}^q$ then raise everything to the power of $\frac 1 {2-q}$.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much.